# ASP.Net sub menu doesn’t display in IE after setting filter gradient.

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8, filter, z-index

I’m using an asp.net (4.0) menu control.

In order to deal with the “Menu Flickering” problem I’m setting the display for the submenu’s to none. The problem I encountered is that the sub-sub menu’s (the third level) doesn’t display in IE (at least IE 7-8) when I use a filter for the gradient.

I think that the filter gradient is somehow messing around with the z-index, since if I remove the z-index set by asp.net using the built in IE developer tools the sub menu displays (with the wrong z-index, but at least it appears). I’ve tried setting the z-index manually using either css or JavaScript on page load, but I can’t seem to get it to display.

Here’s the css and markup:

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">

   .MenuFix ul li ul
   {
     display:none; 
   }
    div.menu ul ul 
   {
     background-color: #003775;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#003775), to(#001F42));
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #003775, #001F42);
    /*Either filter causes the problem*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#003775, endColorstr=#001F42); 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#003775, endColorstr=#001F42)"; 
     position:absolute;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div class="PageWrapper">
       <div class="header">
       <div class="MainMenu MenuFix">
       <asp:Menu ID="mnMainMenu" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="menu" runat="server"  
         StaticSubMenuIndent="16px" DynamicPopOutImageTextFormatString="" 
            StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False">
         <DynamicMenuStyle />
         <Items>
         <asp:MenuItem  Text="Home" />
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Top Level Item 2">
               <asp:MenuItem  Text="Sub Item" />
               <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu" >
                    <asp:MenuItem  Text="Not Displayed" />
                    <asp:MenuItem  Text="Not Displayed" />               
              </asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Item" />
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem  Text="Top Level Item 3" />
         </Items>
         <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="10px" VerticalPadding="5px" />
        </asp:Menu>
      </div>
   </div> 

   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Transparent PNG's are a supported feature of IE 7.  You might get rid of that DXImageTransform call and just handle it in css like you would for other browsers.

The only reason to have a DXImageTransform reference is to support IE 6; which has become a tiny percentage of the normal user base (less than 2% and falling each month).

**More information:**
http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/davidcilley/archive/2007/03/14/ie7-dximagetransform-and-png-transparency-problem.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/04/26/412263.aspx

Comment: I'm using DXImageTransform to display a gradient in IE, If I remove it will display correctly but without a gradient in IE (which is what I'm currently doing). Is it possible (In IE 8) to display a gradient using plain css?

Comment: @Jack: use a transparent PNG of a given size.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I don't know in advance what size (both width and height) the sub-menu will be (there can be multiple sub-menu's) in order to create the PNG. I guess I could use a gradient that starts and ends (repeatable in both directions), but that's not really what I was looking for.